# Can we define $\text dW$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, differentiation, notation

I am currently taking applied thermodynamics at my university, and for the definition of entropy this is the formula used in the book (Thermodynamic for Engineers by Moran, Shapiro, Boettner, Bailey): $\text dS=\delta Q/T$. Here, the differential symbol $\text d$ is not used for the differential of $Q$. Can we define $\text dQ$ or similar expressions regarding energy, work, like $\text dW$, or $\text dE$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36150/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506194/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Have you covered work in mechanics yet?

Comment: That is not the calculation of entropy change that Moran et al indicate.  The integral of that quantity for an **internally reversible** process between two thermodynamic equilibrium states of a closed system is what they indicate as the change in entropy.  And, they use the quantity $\delta Q$ to indicate that the differential amount of heat added to the system is a path-dependent quantity.  So, in this context, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use different differential notation for heat and work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701026/)